# Display text or code content on a div while typing in the textbox like markdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown

I want to display text or code content on a div while I am typing in the textbox like markdown. Here is how far I got.

**Script to show the content on div**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#title').keyup(function(e){
var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/[]/g, '');
$("#result").html(keyed);
});
});
</script>
```

**html part**

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

It is working. But I want that when user types `<table>` tag it should not take it as a input and should not display anything

Answer (score 0):

The only character that shows when typing tags is the open tag.  I wrote some code to handle that open tag when typed in.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#title').keyup(function(e){
    var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/[]/g, '');
    if(keyed == '<')
    {
        $('#title').keyup(function(e){
            var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/[]/g,'');
            $('#result"').html('<' + keyed);
        });
    }
    else
    $("#result").html(keyed);
 });
});
```

Comment: I just realized that if you literally wanted to print out <table> you would not be able to do so, based on the use of jquery.html().

Comment: it is working like previous one i provided, i mean i just want that it should work like Stackoverflow text editor, bt in my case when i type this code       ``<table width="100%"><td height="30" bgcolor="blue"></td></table>`` it displays the table structure. otherwise can you suggest me any markdown editor which is simple ti impliment with php. @cabey

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I misunderstood the question.  I'm not sure of a markdown editor you can implement yourself easily.  There are markdown editors out there like textbox.io.  I would imagine it's not the simplest application to write yourself.  I'm not sure if I can be of much help then.  Thanks.